Stability of pure(ideal) integrator and pure(ideal) differentiator in BIBO sense?
How to realize Poles and zeros at infinity??especially through transfer function?
I was going through above Question and what i am able to understand both pure(ideal) integrator and pure(ideal) differentiator are unstable in BIBO sense.
Please correct me if my understanding is not correct

In both cases it's straightforward to come up with a bounded input signal that causes an unbounded output signal. Take the unit step as an input:
$$x(t)=u(t)\tag{1}$$
Clearly, $x(t)$ is bounded: $|x(t)|\le 1$.
The ideal differentiator's output is a Dirac impulse:
$$y(t)=u'(t)=\delta(t)\tag{2}$$
The output of the ideal integrator is linearly increasing:
$$y(t)=\int_{-\infty}^tu(\tau)d\tau=t\,u(t)\tag{3}$$
Hence, a unit step signal at the input causes both systems to produce an unbounded output signal, and, consequently, neither of them is BIBO-stable.
